# Using mojorra implementaiton on Websphere Application Server 8

Tags: primefaces, liferay, mojarra, websphere-8

I think that I'm stucked with ideas. I'm trying to move liferay portlets from the weblogic to WAS 8. On the weblogic I have been using mojorra implementation for JSF 2.0 and primefaces as a component library. I've installed primefaces on the WAS, and when I was trying to move portlets probles started popping.

First problem is that WAS constantly trying to use myfaces as a JSF implementation - I know this because myfaces throws exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   factoryName'javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletCacheFactory'
>               at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.checkFactoryName(FactoryFinder.java:383)

I have following dependencies in maven pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And for the WAS application I set class loader to load my classes first. But this didn't help. To be sure I configured new classloader for server - but the situtation repeat again. Last idea that I've is to define mojarra jars as a shared libraries - but then I've got ClassFormatException (I havn't time to investigate it).

Any ideas?

---

After adding mojorra classes to the WAR and changing the classloader I've got exception:

> [7/17/12 18:52:25:072 CEST] 0000002c config        E   Critical error
>   during deployment:
>                                        com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED!
>   factoryName 'javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletCacheFactory'
>               at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:375)
>               at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
>               at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1649)
>               at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)

I traced the exception and found that only factoryfinder from the myfaces implementation maybe I should add other dependendency to the project beside that which are already there (jsf-api, jsf-impl)?

---

After specify jsf libraries as a shared library and pointing them as a reference to my war - initalization went with success without any error - other problem is that now liferay is throwing exception:

> 01:21:16,956 ERROR [LiferayFacesContext:61] Instance not initialized
>   -- caller might be static 01:21:16,960 ERROR [LiferayLocalePhaseListener:87] 
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.liferay.faces.portal.lifecycle.LiferayLocalePhaseListener.setLocale
>       (LiferayLocalePhaseListener.java:67)

Maybe it's because I should also define liferay libraries as a shared - I'll try it in seconds.

And the following exception is:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.liferay.faces.bridge.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRendererBridgeImpl.encodeBegin
>   (HeadRendererBridgeImpl.java:133)

Have no idea if this two exception are related to each other - but the result is that my portlets won't work :(

Comment: in my case PARENT_LAST helps. which exception do you have by including your mojarra libs under web-inf/lib and setting PARENT_LAST for the module in ear? are you using RAD withing WAS8?

Answer (score 1):

It's completely possible using some custom classloader magic in WebSphere. See this thread here:

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6860

Comment: looks promising, I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: ok, some new facts - I've defined libraries as a shared library for newly created classloader and all artefacts starts. but the problem is during running portlet I've got the exception with incompatibile class javax.servlet.ServletContext - as I found liferay was build on top of the version 2.5.0 but WAS8 is delivered with version 2.6.0

Comment: did you follow all the directions? Scroll down and make sure you read the bit about isolated classloaders and how websphere makes you start from scratch every time you make a change.

Comment: yes I did - finally I've deleted all configuration and started do it from a scratch - but you know the end. this what torture me is the story with the class ServletContext, as I tell you WAS respects my clas loaders and I saw my jars as first but he ignore ServletContext class in that jar and chose version of his own jar with greater version against that contained in liferayportal*.war

Comment: The answer is that you can use JSF2.0 + liferay bridge + WAS8 - because the servlet specification implementation it simple can't work - after downgrading to WAS7 everything works great